# Css name changed in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Hi do anyone have notice the name changes in css of Sharepoint online before we are using below class to  hide page title

```
 div[class^='pageTitle_']
  {
    display: none;
  }
```

but now pageTitle_ its changed to different name

Like to check its for me only or its for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SharePoint Online page title element screenshot:

[image]

This is my SharePoint 2013 page title element screenshot:
[image]

They are same.

Comment: in Modern Ui pages i get like below class="ip_ab_je"

Comment: Yes,My page is the same as yours.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation